# Move connectionstring to appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dao

I have the following DAO code:

```
using Dapper;
using PerformanceComWebAPI.Modelos;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

namespace PerformanceComWebAPICompleto.DAO
{
    public class ClienteDAO
    {
        //string da conexão com a base de dados
        private const string connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=TesteDapper;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
        /// <summary>
        /// Listar todos os cliente da base de dados
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public List<Cliente> Listar()
        {
            var sql = "select * from dbo.Cliente";
            List<Cliente> clientes = new List<Cliente>();

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                clientes = connection.Query<Cliente>(sql).ToList();
            }

            return clientes;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Metodo que recupera o cliente pelo id
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="idCliente">id cliente que vai ser recuperado</param>
        /// <returns>O cliente que correspondente do cliente ou null quando não tiver cliente com id</returns>
        public Cliente RecuperarPorID(int idCliente)
        {
            var sql = "select * from dbo.Cliente where id = @id";

            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                cliente = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<Cliente>(sql, new { id = idCliente });
            }

            return cliente;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know how I can move the connection string from this page and insert it in the appsettings.json file so I can reuse it with other pages.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core the configuration system is very flexible, and the connection string could be stored in `appsettings.json`, an environment variable, the user secret store, or another configuration source. See the [Configuration section of the ASP.NET Core documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html) for more details. The following example shows the connection string stored in `appsettings.json`.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
}
```

The context is typically configured in `Startup.cs` with the connection string being read from configuration. Note the `GetConnectionString()` method looks for a configuration value whose key is `ConnectionStrings:<connection string name>`. You need to import the [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration) namespace to to use this extension method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase")));
}
```

Comment: I've already tried exactly how you tell me.

Error: "the type or namespace name unity" BloggingContext 'could not be found ".

In which file do I enter this code ?:

public class BloggingContext: DbContext
{
     public BloggingContext (DbContextOptions <BloggingContext> options): base (options)
     {

     }
     public DbSet <CustomerTB> CustomerTB {get; set; }
}

Comment: You don't need to move that code, you just need to reference it in `Startup.cs`.

Comment: I have no context class. I would like to know where to insert it? In Startup.cs or where should it be inserted?

Comment: Hi! First of all welcome to StackOverflow! Would you like to help you navigate your first question? I know it can be confusing and even intimidating having been there myself. 

Your original question dealt with moving the connection string. If you have an another question, it is best to open a new question. This allows future users to find that answer as well.